# Aggregate not populating chart correctly in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

Below, I've attached a sample of my data as well as a sample of the chart output.  I want to aggregate the data and include one row with this number; however, SSRS is just showing multiple of the same value.

In the example below, you'll notice there are 8 rows in Unit 1 and 8 rows in Unit 2, a 
total of 13.  How can I get Unit 1 to have one row which shows 8 and one row in Unit 2 to show 5?  Currently, the expression is **=COUNT(Fields!SubID.Value, "DataSet1")**.

I've also tried adding in a column full of the number **1** which I could use to Sum on, but that produced the same results.

Originally I was doing this all in SQL; that is, producing the exact output I want in SQL and then charting in SSRS.  However, this is no longer a viable solution as the end user would like to be able to drill down into the details of the report.  I do imagine, if there is no easy way to do this (which I feel like there has to be), that I could write two queries, having one show the report and the other show the details.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of your count expression is the problem.

Don't use this:

```
=COUNT(Fields!SubID.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Try something like this instead:

```
=COUNT(Fields!SubID.Value, "UnitGroupName")
```

The group name should match what is shown in BIDS as the name you've given the grouping, such as under Row Groups.

Comment: Great, thanks!  You always have the solution to my SSRS problems :)

Comment: Thanks... I spend lots of time in SQL and C# as well, but others seem to answer those questions pretty quickly: I end up with the tiny corner that is SSRS. (And thanks for the decently written and illustrated questions.)